# Does git show command need to access network?

Tags: git

We are executing `git show` in a remote server, and found the sometimes the command completed in several seconds but sometimes it took more than 10 minutes. Does the command need to access network or github server?

Comment: No. If you clone the repo locally you can do it there. In fact that is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `git show` does not require network access.

The fundamental principle of distributed version control systems, like git, is that every contributor/machine has a complete copy of the repository and all the actions -with the exception of updating like pull,push etc.- are local.